# Vb.net code cannot write from text file to my.settings variable

Tags: vb.net, winforms, replace

This is my code:

```
Private Sub ButtonRead_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonRead.Click
    Dim path As String = "plik.txt"

    If File.Exists(path) Then
        Dim lines As String() = File.ReadAllLines(path)

        For Each line As String In lines
            For Each setting As System.Configuration.SettingsPropertyValue In My.Settings.PropertyValues
                Dim variableName As String = setting.Name
                Dim variableValue As Object = setting.PropertyValue

                If line.StartsWith(variableName + ":") Then
                    Dim line2 As String = line
                    Dim variableName2 As String = variableName
                    Dim variableValue2 As String = variableValue

                    If line2.Contains(variableName2) Then
                        If line2.Contains(variableValue2) Then
                            If line2.Contains(":") Then
                                line2 = line2.Replace(variableName2, """")
                                line2 = line2.Replace(":", "")
                                line2 = line2.Replace(variableValue2, variableValue2 + """")
                                RichTextBox1.Text = line2 + Environment.NewLine + variableName2 + variableValue2
                                My.Settings(variableName2).value = line2
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

This code reads the file "plik.txt", check if exists and write the file's text into a my.settings string, in the file "plik.txt" in this text file is: Testowa:siemanko2, program tries to replace Testowa (variableName) into ", : into nothing and variableValue into variableValue and " but it's not working beacuse this code can't put the line to my.settings variable because is not a string, then i turn off this code to replace the my.settings variable and tries to get inforation about other variables "RichTextBox1.Text = line2 + Environment.NewLine + variableName2" and this is what i get:

"siemanko2"
Testowasiemanko2

it's all good but it's a error "System.MissingMemberException:"
can I get help with this problem?

i tried to make if ....contains(), add at the start and the end of the string the ""

Comment: Please tell us what you want to do instead of how you are trying to do it, it might make the question clearer.